# How can I uniquely identify a USB key from C#?

Tags: c#, windows

I'd like to be able to detect when a USB key is inserted.  Furthermore, if I can distinguish between USB key A and USB key B then I am in even better shape.  Lastly, if I can uniquely identify the key using some sort of hardware serial number, MAC address or whatever, then I'm in the best shape of all.

Basically I am looking at using a USB key as a hardware dongle to "unlock" my C# application.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

All hard-drives have a Serial Number, USB flash drives are no different.  Here is an article, with a sample project, that shows [how to get the non-volatile serial number](http://www.cfdan.com/posts/Retrieving_Non-Volatile_USB_Serial_Number_Using_C_Sharp.cfm).  Basically you just need to enumerate the system drives and grab the PNPDeviceID property.

Comment: Thanks, worked perfectly for getting the serial.  I don't suppose I could get "lucky" twice and learn about a way to get an event notification when a drive is added to the system?

Comment: Actually here's a related question that looks like what I am looking for: <a href="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/271907/how-to-detect-using-c-if-a-pendrive-is-plugged-into-a-usb-port">click<a/>

Answer (score 0):

You need to retrieve the key's [Hardware ID](http://ezinearticles.com/?Unique-Hardware-ID-in-C&id=1057498).

I don't see how to subscribe to the plugged-in event, but you could always have the user click a button too.

Comment: I believe the volumeserialnumber is changed each time the USB drive is formatted by Windows.  There is a separate serial number that is non-volatile and probably is better to use.

Answer (score 0):

Hard Disk Id is not unique. Maybe theoretically it is, but in practice it is not. This is without any crack, emulator or any special program.