# Linking FriendlyNames from the Registry to drive letters for USB storage devices

Tags: c++, winapi, registry, usb

I am writing an application that allows Syncing to USB storage devices and I would like to display the `FriendlyName` for the devices that can be found in the registry at `HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Enum\USBSTOR\`

I am using `GetLogicalDrives` to get the list of available devices, `GetDriveType` to filter by `DRIVE_REMOVABLE` and `GetVolumeInformation` to retrieve the volume name and serial number.

I would like to also get the `FriendlyName` out of the registry by linking the `USBSTOR` entries to a drive letter so I know which entry is which drive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tricky but possible. Have a peek at [my post here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/271907/how-to-detect-using-c-if-a-pendrive-is-plugged-into-a-usb-port/272005#272005). That approach is roughly in the right direction here, too. You don't want to use undocumented registry fields. Instead, use the Device Information Functions from the SetupAPI and Configuration Management API